# System clock on my Glass device is wrong?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

So I'm developing an app for Glass which involves setting alarms for certain times and dates. However, when looking at the logcats on Android Studio, I can see that the time is wrong--WAY wrong. Like 2 weeks, 9 hours and some change off. It is my impression that the time shown in the logs is the system time of the device.

Indeed, when I start the glass device, the clock shows an incorrect time. Interestingly, when I go to the calendar app, that gives the correct date.

I can't figure out how to set the date and time anywhere in the settings of the device. Has anyone dealt with this?

Comment: Very interesting issue. I haven't dealt with anything like this myself.

Comment: Is the timezone (in Settings -> Device info -> More details) correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain, but I think the time is only ever synced from a paired phone, not from the internet.
So are you pairing the device to a phone or connecting directly to wi-fi?
In not paired to a phone, try that.

Comment: Really? Glass gets it's time from a paired device? Where'd you find that?

Comment: I've just noticed that if the time is out it tends to get fixed when paired. I have no supporting evidence to back that up though I'm afraid.  Also that is definitely how it works on android wear (although I'm aware they are very different systems).

Comment: I'm still not positive exactly what happened but I believe this is the case. It might have to do with the MyGlass app for iPhone still being pretty buggy, and that might have been what messed it up in the first place. But when I paired it to an android phone, the issue was "resolved"